# c# Find out which shortcut is clicked

Tags: c#, directory, shortcut

I would like to find the folder of a shortcut that opens my program.

I have a program that installs in the program files folder and creates a folder in the c drive with a shortcut and a bunch of other files. My program checks for the existence of those files. If someone decides to change the folder name or move it somewhere else than it can't find the files.

I have tried `Environment.CurrentDirectory` but that gives the exe directory not the shortcut that was clicked.

I know there are an infinite number of ways I could do it differently/better, but is there is a way to find the path of the shortcut that was clicked to open this program?

Comment: Make all the shortcuts pass a parameter with the folder path?

Comment: investigate your installer program, to see how can you change created shortcut parameters and for every one specify some particular value. So inside the program will be able to understand which shortcut was clicked, based on parameter.

Comment: I don't really need to know which shortcut is click but which folder the shortcut is in. Windows must keep track of which shortcut was clicked. So how do I find that information. (Assuming it exists)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get that information in the way you are asking.  The .exe only knows its own location and things relative to it.  It does not know how it was run only that it was run.

The only possible suggestion I could give would be for you to add command line parameters with the information and make sure they are in the target of your shortcut but I do not think that is what you are asking for.